# Plot points and polygons from the same data in tmap

Tags: r, r-sf, tmap

I am trying to plot multiple geometries from the same data set in `tmap`.

Consider the following data set. Some of the features are centroids (points) and others are polygons.

```r
library(sf)
library(tmap)
nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package = "sf"))
set.seed(1)
idx <- sort(sample(nrow(nc), 20))
nc[idx, ] <- st_centroid(nc[idx, ])
```

I'd like to plot the polygons and the points. By default, `tm_dots` and all other functions plotting points are also working for polygons (cf. [here](https://r-tmap.github.io/tmap-book/layers.html)). But I wonder if it's possible to use `tm_dots` to plot only the points objects, **from the same data**.

I know I can do something with subsetting like:

```r
tm_shape(nc[st_dimension(nc) == 2, ]) +
  tm_polygons() +
  tm_shape(nc[st_dimension(nc) == 0, ]) +
  tm_dots()
```

But I wonder whether there is something simpler like this:

```r
tm_shape(nc) +
  tm_polygons() +
  tm_dots(geom = "POINT")
```

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: I - and this is a personal observation, not a general recommendation - would try hard to avoid situations like the one you describe. You are converting a specific geometry column of type MULTIPOLYGON to a generic one of type GEOMETRY (consisting of a mixture of POINTs and MULTIPOLYGONS). Doing so is legal, but opens a whole can of worms  - you can no longer rely on your objects to have an area, or contiguity neighborhoods. I would do my best to keep points and polygons separated; possibly in two geometry columns if I was hard pressed, but not like this.

Comment: In my real-case scenario, I extract data from OpenStreetMap, and while some features are points, some are polygons. Keeping these features under the same geometry would actually mean reducing polygons to points. I want to deal with both geometries in the same data.frame, hence my question.